# package ‘ggplot2’ is not available for this version of R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-library

Can't get the ggplot2.

I can post more data if you let me know what I should run, but here is the error and the version.

```
> library("ggplot2")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’
```

My R version

```
>version()
```

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32arch           x86_64os             mingw32crt            ucrtsystem         x86_64, mingw32statusmajor          4minor          2.2year           2022month          10day            31svn rev        83211language       Rversion.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

Comment: I'd try re-installing ggplot `install.packages("ggplot2")` - it should install the dependencies (like `rlang`) by default. If you continue to have the `rlang` problem, install that directly `install.packages("rlang")`.

Comment: The linked FAQ has quite a few more suggestions you can try if those first ones don't do the trick.